# imagemagic create an image by repeating the given transparent .png image

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have a transparent ".png" image and I want to create a new image of the given width and height by repeating that image. When I do this command from console:

```
/usr/bin/convert -size 1200x1200 tile:'red50x5.png' 'resulting_image.png'
```

then a new image is created 1200x1200 big but it is without the transparency of the original iamge.

when I do:

```
/usr/bin/convert 'red50x5.png' -verbose info
```

im getting

> info PNG 50x5 50x5+0+0 8-bit sRGB 2c 311B 0.000u 0:00.000

My question is how to create the 1200x1200 image without loosing the transparency of the original image. I just need to get a new image repeated without any change in transparency!

Comment: Try adding "-background none" to your command.

Comment: Also, adding "+repage" before the output will make that "info:" give correct geometry information for the entire image. Without repaging, the geometry is based on just the first image in the tiling.

Comment: unfortunetly -background none did not do what I needed. Image is still not transparent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option to -tile to set the number of tiles in Imagemagick. However here are two different ways to make a 5x2 tiling. The following is Unix syntax.

```
# resize transparent logo image
convert logot.png -resize 35% logot2.png
```

Method 1 (uses append):

```
convert logot2.png -write mpr:img +delete \( mpr:img -duplicate 4 +append \) \( +clone \) -append -background none -extent 1200x1200 x.png
```

Method 2 (uses montage):

```
montage logot2.png -duplicate 9 -background none -geometry +0+0 -tile 5x2 miff:- | convert - -background none -extent 1200x1200 x.png
```

[image]

For Windows, remove the \ escapes from before the parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

Using Imagemagick the key is to change the compose method to copy. So

```
# create transparent image
convert logo: -transparent white logot.png
```

[image]

```
convert -size 1200x1200 -compose copy tile:logot.png x.png
```

[image]

Comment: hello fmw42, I have accepted your answer it does what I wanted. Now I have another question. Can we repeat only certain amount of times? lets say generate an image 1200x1200 big but repeat the given image only lets say 5 times in x direction or so?